# Error installing TensorFlow on Windows 10 (Python 3.8.3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.8

On Windows 10 with Python 3.8.3. I installed TensorFlow using

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

but get the following error. Any recommendations on how I can fix this?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-17-07ec96d933aa> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib as mpl
      4 import sklearn
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow import keras

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sunel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: There are a number of suggestions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39007) that might give you some leads.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 support starts TensorFlow 2.2 or later. Hence you are facing above issue.

You can install latest version of Tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow`. TensorFlow 2 packages require a `pip version > 19.0`.

You need to download and install/update the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are still facing DLL load failed errors, possible reasons are

- Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits (It should be 64 bit)
- There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded.

For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#install-tensorflow-2).